# transpose table dynamically in excel

Tags: excel, transpose

I need some advice for the following task, I have an Excel sheet with 2 columns RESPONSIBLE and SERVICE (see Sheet1 of [Attached file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AigFpWk8h0GO8x7eFY727sPkR_39) )

I need to create on another Excel sheet the matrix as Sheet2 in attached file.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a helper column in sheet1?

Comment: You want a vba solution for this or just excel formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following array formula in B2 and drag/copy as required:

```
=IF(AND($A2<>"",B$1<>"")=TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2&B$1,Sheet1!$A:$A&Sheet1!$B:$B,0))=TRUE,"x",""),"")
```

To populate the column headers use the following array formula in B1 and drag/copy:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100),0)),"")
```

To populate the row headers use the following array formula in A2 and drag/copy:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100),0)),"")
```

Enter all the above formulas with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

**I tested the above formulas by increasing the data and it slowed down my excel file. The reason is most likely the first formula.**

If you add a helper column in sheet1 then you can add this in C2 (not an array formula):

```
=A2&B2
```

Then in sheet2, B2 you can use (not an array formula):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2&B$1,Sheet1!$C:$C,0))=TRUE,"x","")
```

This will substantially increase the speed to normal levels as the number of array formulas in the sheet are materially reduced.

**Or**

You can simply use a pivot table. Enter "Service" as column label and value, and "Responsible" as row label. The value should show count of service. The only difference will be that instead of "x" it will show a 1. You will also have to refresh the pivot table whenever you update the data.

Comment: Thank you for your help Nitesh, I've forgot another important requirement, if I add a new row in Sheet1 with a new category, for instance James with NETWORK, the new category should be automatically added to the column in Sheet 2, is it possible to accomplish this task ?  Many thanks for all your help Fabrizio

Comment: Use the second array formula from my answer. "To populate the column headers use the following array formula in B1... "